# Insert HTML at runtime?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I need to write some code that places one of 3 choices of "blocks" of html in a specified place on the page. How can I do this?

I was thinking I can use single value databinding, but I don't think this is the correct way.

I'm using ASP.NET c#.

Edit: here is what it might look like:

```
MapPlaceholder.InnerHtml = @"<div class="mapContainer smallMap" id="smallGrid" runat="server" visible="false">
    <div id="node1" class="gridBox" runat="server">
    </div>
    <div id="node2" class="gridBox" runat="server">
    </div>
    <div id="node3" class="gridBox" runat="server">
    </div>
    <div id="node4" class="gridBox" runat="server">
    </div>
    <div id="node5" class="gridBox" runat="server">
    </div>
    <div id="node6" class="gridBox" runat="server">
    </div>
    <div id="node7" class="gridBox" runat="server">
    </div>
    <div id="node8" class="gridBox" runat="server">
    </div>
    <div id="node9" class="gridBox" runat="server">
    </div>
</div>";
```

and in the `.aspx` page:

```
<div id="MapPlaceholder" runat="server"></div>
```

One more thing, how can I tell C# to actually write the `"` in the string? It isnt working currently because it stop at the first `"` it finds.

Edit: I have another problem.

```
                        MapPlaceholder.InnerHtml = block1;
                    HtmlGenericControl smallGrid = (HtmlGenericControl)MapPlaceholder.FindControl("smallGrid");
                    containerName = "smallGrid";
                    smallGrid.Visible = true;
                    smallGrid.Attributes["Style"] = "background-image:url('" + du.getMapBackgroundImage(mapId) + "'); " + "width:300px; height:300px;";
                    containerName = "smallGrid";
```

This is what i am trying to do, but the FindControl always returns null. I debugged this and it seems that the html code is being added, but only after the pageload ends. Is there anyway i can tell c# to "render" the div so i can work with it like i need to?

Comment: can you show some code, your current page markup and tell us where in it you would like to inject your HTML and how your HTML looks like?

Comment: I posted another bit at the bottom, because it wont work for me.

Comment: You can't use `(HtmlGenericControl)MapPlaceholder.FindControl("smallGrid")` if the contents of `MapPlaceholder` are written as a string. There is no control named `smallgrid` to find.

Comment: So the way i did it, it doesnt count as a control even thou its exactly the same code?

Answer (score 3):

To have double quotes in code, you need to have two of them when using `@` so it would be:

```
MapPlaceholder.InnerHtml = @"<div class=""mapContainer smallMap"" id=""smallGrid"" runat=""server"" visible=""false"">
    <div id=""node1"" class=""gridBox"" runat=""server"">
    </div>
    <div id=""node2"" class=""gridBox"" runat=""server"">
    </div>
    <div id=""node3"" class=""gridBox"" runat=""server"">
    </div>
    <div id=""node4"" class=""gridBox"" runat=""server"">
    </div>
    <div id=""node5"" class=""gridBox"" runat=""server"">
    </div>
    <div id=""node6"" class=""gridBox"" runat=""server"">
    </div>
    <div id=""node7"" class=""gridBox"" runat=""server"">
    </div>
    <div id=""node8"" class=""gridBox"" runat=""server"">
    </div>
    <div id=""node9"" class=""gridBox"" runat=""server"">
    </div>
</div>";
```

To your original question: have three strings with the possible "blocks" then assign the proper string:

```
string block1 = @"<div class=""mapContainer smallMap"">block 1</div>......";
string block2 = @"<div class=""mapContainer smallMap"">block 2</div>......";
string block3 = @"<div class=""mapContainer smallMap"">block 3</div>.......";
switch (myCond) {
    case 1:
        MapPlaceholder.InnerHtml= block1;
        break;
    case 2:
        MapPlaceholder.InnerHtml= block2;
        break;
    case 3:
        MapPlaceholder.InnerHtml= block3;
        break;
}
```

Edit: looks like you need different approach. First, put all blocks inside the `.aspx` under `MapPlaceholder` control directly:

```
<div id="MapPlaceholder" runat="server">
    <div class="mapContainer smallMap" id="smallGrid1" runat="server" visible="false">
        block 1 contents here...
    </div>
    <div class="mapContainer smallMap" id="smallGrid2" runat="server" visible="false">
        block 2 contents here...
    </div>
    <div class="mapContainer smallMap" id="smallGrid3" runat="server" visible="false">
        block 3 contents here...
    </div>
</div>
```

Having this, just show the proper control based on the condition:

```
switch (myCond) {
    case 1:
        smallGrid1.Visible = true;
        break;
    case 2:
        smallGrid2.Visible = true;
        break;
    case 3:
        smallGrid3.Visible = true;
        break;
}
```

This way you don't have to mess with strings of raw HTML and can change the layout from the `.aspx` which is more convenient.

Comment: Why do i need to write double ""? Isnt that what the @ is for?

Comment: The `@` tell the compiler "this string is in Visual Basic format" and in that format, you still need to escape double quotes.

Comment: You can't fix that problem unless you change the logic. Either work with pure HTML, or with controls. You can't mix it like you're trying to do now.

Comment: What do you mean? I want to generate a dynamic grid to the aspx page.

How can i work with just pure html?

Comment: If i type the divs by hand in the aspx page, then i can interact with them and do what i want from codebehind, so why cant i do it like this?

Comment: Thanks for the concern, but that was actually my first implementation. I quickly found out that it wont work for me, mainly because each div will contain an image (and you cant have images with same ID). What i am going to try now is to create a user control to and give it data to generate my map.

Something i need to know is, is GenericHtmlControl the way to programmatically specify its a div?

Like when you create a textbox and then add it at runtime, so it knows its a textbox, but with a div.

Comment: You can give each image different ID, can't see what's the problem. Anyway yes, `<div>` can be created by `new HtmlGenericControl("div");`

Comment: Anyway, im going to try and implement this using a user control. Atleast its better implementation and will allow me to handle events for the map.

Answer (score 1):

on Page Load you can insert what you need dynamically.

a tip: you can insert with a Label over its Text property an html block, javascript or jquery codes

```
Label myLabel = new Label();
myLabel.Text = @"html text";

Page.Controls.Add(myLabel);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question really is "how to place blocks of HTML onto the page" as a (very basic) example, you might find something like this useful:

ASPX code:

```
<div runat="server" id="mydiv"></div>
```

C# code:

```
mydiv.InnerHtml = "<span>hi</span>";
```

or

```
HtmlGenericControl c = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
c.InnerHtml = "hi";
mydiv.Controls.Add(c);
```

DataBinding is more for pushing dynamic values to page content from, e.g. a database.

Answer (score 0):

The PlaceHolder control may be what you need:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label NewLabel = new Label();
    NewLabel.Text = "Hello World!";

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(NewLabel); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add HTML tags With concatenation of the string at label text or others

```
labelc.text="Html tags code here";
```